# Is there a way to reference a constant using a string in javascript/JSX (React framework)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constants, jsx

```js
import building from '../../../public/lotties/building.json'
import chest from '../../../public/lotties/chest.json'
import clock from '../../../public/lotties/clock.json'
import creditcard from '../../../public/lotties/creditcard.json'
import dnalottie from '../../../public/lotties/dna.json'
import engineering from '../../../public/lotties/engineering.json'
import handshake from '../../../public/lotties/handshake.json'
import hospital from '../../../public/lotties/hospital.json'
import map from '../../../public/lotties/map.json'
import navpinsfalling from '../../../public/lotties/navpinsfalling.json'
import radar from '../../../public/lotties/radar.json'
import rocket from '../../../public/lotties/rocket.json'
import student from '../../../public/lotties/student.json'
import teacher from '../../../public/lotties/teacher.json'
import tree from '../../../public/lotties/tree.json'
import trophy from '../../../public/lotties/trophy.json'
import virus from '../../../public/lotties/virus.json'
import wallet from '../../../public/lotties/wallet.json'
```

I have a GenericLottie Component and I want to pass in a prop like 'wallet' and reference the imported constant.

```js
    const animData = this.props.name;
    //
    const animData = {this.props.name};
    //
    const animData = `${this.props.name}`;
```

I've tried all the above lines of code, none of them work. It's clear I need to review string literals and how they work.
Is there a workaround to my problem? If not, I can go through and code each one individually, I'd prefer not to.

Comment: yes: `globalThis[this.props.name]`, but that's also pretty terrible code design and you should not trust that `this.props.name` contains a valid string.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're asking. `wallet` for instance appears to be a json file, so for simplicity, let's call it an object. Are you wanting to pass an object to a component and have it do something specific with it based on the object name? Or what is the desire? Can you show us something you've tried? Your example you have above is too vague for me to pick up on your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* what you're wanting to do is this?
Written using functional component rather than class, so there's no need for `this` when referencing props.

**SomeOtherComponent.js**

```
import wallet from '../../../public/lotties/wallet.json';
import GenericLottie from '../../wherever';

const SomeOtherComponent = () => {
  return <GenericLottie name={wallet} />;
};
```

**GenericLottie.js**

```
const GenericLottie = (props) => {
  // This should be the 'wallet' you imported in the parent component!
  const animData = props.name;

  ...
};
```